# Windows Phone 8 - LongListSelector argumentexception when returning to previous page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am having an issue where when I navigate forward and go back, I get an argumentexception for my longlistselector. I have only found the solution of catching the exception, but then the items are missing for about 10 seconds. Is there a way around this? Am I missing something that would cause this issue? Here is my code. Note that this code is only called when loaded, not on navigatedto. Thanks.

```
<self:LongListSelectorEx Name="lbChatFriends" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,80,0,80" />

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                foreach (JObject currjobject in jsonFriendArray.Children<JObject>())
                {
                    DispatchChatControls(currjobject);
                }
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    if (!communityonlybool && showFriendsStartup && showingFriendDisplay)
                    {
                        usersSearchChat.IsEnabled = true;
                    }
                    lbChatFriends.ItemsSource = listChatFriends;
                    friendsLoaded = true;
                    chatprogbar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                    if (mainpivot.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        chatStatusTimer.Start();
                    }
                }));
            });
```

Comment: For exactly which statement you are getting the exception?

Comment: Check that names of the elements in the list are unique. Same names can be a cause.

Comment: I am not getting an exception in that code, I am showing the code that runs on load on the first page to put the items into the longlistselector. I then have a button that takes you to a new page (navigates forward) but say the user presses the back button on their windows phone, I get the exception. It seems to be a refresh layout update issue.

Comment: Each item is a usercontrol, I have named them but also tried naming each item on each user control, no success. I have read about a argumentexception bug with wp8 but not sure why I am getting it because they say it only happens when removing an item, I don't do anything lol.

Comment: Show us the exact code where you are getting exception with the exception details.

Comment: It would just cause an unhandled exception in the App.xaml.cs file. I will post a screenshot later with the exception details.

Comment: Here are the screenshots I was able to get. When I click Continue after the exception occurs, it does not popup about symbols breaking or letting me get extra into on a stack trace, the app just closes.

http://oi62.tinypic.com/52j12h.jpg

http://oi61.tinypic.com/jzvgc7.jpg

Comment: It seems to be a bug in WP8 related to this, but for me it is not when removing items, it is when leaving from an app page back to a previous one.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-US/bec4efbf-269b-4be0-aacc-99c8be59b861/wp8-longlistselector-exception-when-removing-items